# GridView WebForm having multiple checkboxes per row but only 1 per row is allowed to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have code in which a gridview in asp.net webforms spits out 3 checkboxes of which I would like to have Jquery easily traverse through the ID's and ONLY allow 1 checkbox per row to be checked.

They will Always have the same name just that the ending numbers will increase  thus row 1 might not have a number,  but then ending in 1  then ending in 2  , then they all end of 3  etc...

I could do this regretfully long way of writing a ton of javascript/jquery in which I check for each specific checkbox and those that end in 1, those cannot have any others ending with 1 to be checked, they have to be unchecked.

I was thinking about regex in which I check the beginning of the ID and then the end of the ID and making sense that per ID having "chkCtrl" AND ending with a unique number like "1"  that the specific box being checked will uncheck the other "chkCtrl" ending in 1  .  Thus  Out1 , Y1 , N1

I'm sure that there IS a fast way to do this I just cannot seem to find an example of it.

Example

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Out</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="MainContent_chkCtrlOut" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkCtrl" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="MainContent_chkCtrlY" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkCtrl" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="MainContent_chkCtrlN" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkCtrl" />
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <input id="MainContent_chkCtrlOut1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkCtrl" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="MainContent_chkCtrlY1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkCtrl" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="MainContent_chkCtrlN1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkCtrl" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done by writing a couple of lines of jquery. For example see the code below.

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').removeProp('checked');
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/a3qk0kc1/1/

---

**Edit**

As Tom Stickel has mentioned in the comments using removeProp is a bad idea. It may not work in jquery 2.*. Refer [Tom Stickel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391400/gridview-webform-having-multiple-checkboxes-per-row-but-only-1-per-row-is-allowe/32406327#32406327) for a better way to do this.

Comment: I didn't even think it would be this concise and simple  wow this is awesome

Comment: This is actually NOT going to even work if you change to a newer version of jquery like 2.1.4      .removeProp is bad idea  as well   -  use .prop instead

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer will work in older jquery,  if you changed that selected answer jquery version to a new version the checkboxes do not work.

.removeProp is bad idea  https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/

Taleeb was very close however, I would say to edit that one line.

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of this. I've edited my answer to add a reference to yours..

Comment: When I noticed the removeProp I recalled the > 1.5/1/6 changes and immediately just changed your jsfiddle to a newer jquery version and the checkboxes no longer behaved correctly.   Yes I do find it annoying when methods and properties etc.. in libraries get changed and/or deprecated.   Good work though on a very succinct and precise answer Taleeb